# Why my location data create a unique ID fields each time the location updates were stored in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I had create a Location Listener by FusedLocation. Each time when my logged auth user start to track their location, the location were write under the currentuser user-id but it keep added a different unique ID for each location that were written in the database. I need that 'location' in the same tree with my current login user description ('name' & 'type') and each time my current user have a location changed data, it will overwrite the data in the 'latitude' and 'longitude'. How I can reconstruct my code?

Here my screenshot of my database
[my firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29YMi.jpg)

Here my location.class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


/**
 * Created by AKMAL NIZAR ROSLE on 12/6/2017.
 */

public class DriverActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "DriverActivity";
private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;

private FirebaseAuth auth;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;


Button btnFusedLocation;
TextView tvLocation, textViewUser;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mCurrentLocation;
String mLastUpdateTime;

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //get current user
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(DriverActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");
    //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    createLocationRequest();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver);

    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    textViewUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUser);

    textViewUser.setText("Welcome"+" "+user.getEmail());

    tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);

    btnFusedLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    btnFusedLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            updateUI();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    startLocationUpdates();
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    saveToFirebase();
    updateUI();
}


private void saveToFirebase() {
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    Map mLocations = new HashMap();
    Map  mCoordinate = new HashMap();
    mCoordinate.put("latitude", mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
    mCoordinate.put("longitude", mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    mLocations.put("location", mCoordinate);
    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).push().setValue(mLocations);
}


private void updateUI() {
    Log.d(TAG, "UI update initiated .............");
    if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
        String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        tvLocation.setText("At Time: " + mLastUpdateTime + "\n" +
                "Latitude: " + lat + "\n" +
                "Longitude: " + lng + "\n" +
                "Accuracy: " + mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy() + "\n" +
                "Provider: " + mCurrentLocation.getProvider());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "location is null ...............");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void saveToFirebase() {
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    Map mLocations = new HashMap();
    Map  mCoordinate = new HashMap();
    mCoordinate.put("latitude", mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
    mCoordinate.put("longitude", mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    mLocations.put("location", mCoordinate);
    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).push().setValue(mLocations);
}
```

Just remove the **push()** method in your setValue database operation:

```
private void saveToFirebase() {
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    Map  mCoordinate = new HashMap();
    mCoordinate.put("latitude", mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
    mCoordinate.put("longitude", mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    databaseReference.child(user.getUid() + "/location").setValue(mCoordinate);
}
```

The **push()** method generates a new node with an unique key to your database reference.

Comment: Thank you sir! You save my day. BTW, can you help me in advance, if another log in user (2nd user) want to retrieve the location data of (1st user), how can i write the code for 2nd user to read the ref path such as **" databaseReference.child(user.getUid() + "/location").setValue(mCoordinate); "** ?

Comment: Or can you help me translate the code if I want to use geofire?